# Powershell Get data by group

Tags: powershell

I need some help on this:

I´ve this code:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\ -File | 
Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '_.*$' } | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Group.Fullname } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    echo "file '$($_)'" >> C:\Scripts\Video_Time\input\new.txt
}
```

This code gives me all files in a directory, grouped by name and writes the results to a txt file.

```
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_12.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_17.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_2.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_15.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_4.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_9.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_10.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_16.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_6.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los animales_14.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los animales_3.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_1.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_11.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_5.mp4'
```

I need the result only by same file name at the time, that means each group at the time:

```
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_12.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_17.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\el arte_2.mp4'

file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_15.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_4.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la mÃºsica_9.mp4'

file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_10.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_16.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\la vida de antes_6.mp4'

file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los animales_14.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los animales_3.mp4'


file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_1.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_11.mp4'
file 'C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\los juegos_5.mp4'
```

The idea is override the same txt for each group, execute the rest of code and go back and get other group.

Comment: the `Group-Object` cmdlet can group by _calculated_ values. so define the part of the file name you want to group by and use that. it looks like you want `.BaseName.Split('_')[0]` for your grouping value.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to see that mklement0 posted a working solution to your problem ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following writes the full paths of the files in each group to a file named for the group's grouping criterion, such as `el arte.txt` for the first group:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output -File | 
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '_.*$' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
      $groupName = $_.Name
      $_.Group.FullName | ForEach-Object { "file '$_'" } > "$groupName.txt"
    }
```